# Multiplying signed to unsigned binary numbers in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have tried this for signed * unsigned, it doesn't work, why not?

```
bit unsigned [15:0] a;
bit signed [15:0] b;
bit signed [16:0] c;

c = signed'(b) * signed'({1'b0,a})
```

The result c should be signed, b can be negative.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: Also you are only multiplying `signed` here, so it is not clear how it relates to the title.

Comment: were you intending to multiply a and b? If so, I'm not surprised this code doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you concatenating `b` with a 0 as the MSB? That **does not** give you the absolute value of `b`.

Answer (score 3):

It would have helped if you could have explained what "doesn't work" meant, but I've seen this problem enough times that I think you meant you are seeing what looks like positive values in `c` when `b` has a negative value. Your multiplication is getting truncated so it looks like a positive number.

For example, supposed you had a:40919, b:-27415. The result of that multiplication is -1121794385 (32'hbd22c6af). But `c` is only 17-bits, so it gets truncated to 17'h0c6af.

So you either need to restrict the values in `a` and `b` so the result of the multiplication fits in 17-bits, or increase the size of `c` to 32-bits.

Answer (score -1):

c should have [31:0] instead of 16:0

Comment: Could you expand this answer?